DISPLAY variable is not properly set on SSH connection

I am using Linux server with SSH connection via VScode.
As far as I know and referring the other cases and examples, the environment variable $DISPLAY should be set properly.
In my case, however, this isn't automatically set to properly show GUI application.
For example, when I executed xeyes in the shell, the GUI window won't be forwarded.
$ xeyes
Error: Can't open display: user-ESC4000-E11:10.0

Therefore, as a workaround, I have manually changed this DISPLAY variable by trying to change the variable to one of variables from the command xauth list, i.e.,
$ xauth list
user-ESC4000-E11:12  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  ~~~
user-ESC4000-E11:13  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  ~~~
user-ESC4000-E11:14  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  ~~~
user-ESC4000-E11:11  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  ~~~
user-ESC4000-E11:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  ~~~
$ export DISPLAY=user-ESC4000-E11:11.0
$ xeyes
Error: Can't open display: user-ESC4000-E11:11.0
...
$ export DISPLAY=user-ESC4000-E11:13.0
$ xeyes
(Works!)


However, I think this is not an ideal method to resolve this problem.
Is there any methods to handle this problem so that I can use X11 forwarding without manual setting as above?
For your information, I would like to clarify my SSH configuration as followings:
Host ###
    HostName ###.###.###.###
    Port ####
    User ###
    ForwardAgent yes
    ForwardX11 yes
    ForwardX11Trusted yes
    Compression yes

(assume there are no problems in redacted information)

See if you have something in your shell startup files (.bashrc, etc.) on the remote system which is altering the DISPLAY variable. If ssh is forwarding X, then DISPLAY should be set to the correct value in the remote session. If it's not, that could be because something is altering the value.
